# tkinter value of numbers in a grid

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been playing around with the `tkinter` package placing random bits into a series of `tkinter.Label` objects meant to represent a vector of 8-bit binary values. I have created the following `matrix()` function for this:

```
import tkinter, random

window = tkinter.Tk()

def matrix():

    place = []
    nums  = [0, 1]

    for i in range(8):

        place.append(i)
        A_1 = tkinter.Label(window, text = random.choice(nums))

    A_1.configure(text = random.choice(nums))
    A_1.grid(row = random.choice(place), column = random.choice(place))

    window.after(1, matrix)

matrix()

tkinter.mainloop()
```

I would now like to find the value of the bit in stored in each label to convert each 8-bit row into denary. How can I access the value of a number stored in a `tkinter.Label` object?

Thanks!

Comment: your code creates an infinite number of labels. As soon as it iterates over the list you call `after`, which calls the same function again. And again. And again. ... creating 8 labels per millisecond.

Comment: This code creates a grid of 8 x 8 labels and the number in a random label updates every millisecond.  Is there a way of finding the value any label in the grid?

Comment: You aren't updating a label, you're creating 8 new labels each millisecond, and _then_ updating one.

Comment: Ah yes I see that now.  But is there a way of finding the contents of a particular cell?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* find the value stored in a `tkinter.Label` object using the `cget("text")` function. As an example, the following code will `cget` the `str` value stored in the `tkinter.Label`'s `text` key - in this case, the string `Spam, ham, and eggs.` -  and print it to the console:

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import choice

root = tk.Tk()

my_label = tk.Label(root, text = "Spam, ham, and eggs.")
my_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

my_text = my_label.cget("text")

print(my_text)

root.mainloop()
```

However, this isn't a particularly good way of coding it if we're going to be referencing multiple values across multiple labels. More ideally, we would want to keep track of those text values in a `list` or `dict` independently of the labels, and simply use those stored values for any sort of processing as opposed to drawing them from the labels each time. Alternatively, you could store the `tkinter.Labels` themselves in a list for the purpose of calling `cget()` on them iteratively.

Furthermore, as [Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley) pointed out in the comments, with the way your code is presently implemented, you are not actually updating the labels as you intended but are infinitely recursively writing new labels to the root window on top of the old ones. Additionally, you aren't keeping track of the generated labels nor the values given to them, which makes even accessing them with `cget()` unfeasible.

As an alternative approach, first generate a series of `tkinter.Labels` for your matrix. You may want to store `tkinter.StringVar` objects in the labels instead of `str` objects so that you can easily update the values displayed by the labels with the `tkinter.StringVar` class' `set()` function as opposed to overlaying a new label each time. Finally, instead of recursively updating the matrix without end, consider adding in a control for when to update the matrix, such as a `tkinter.Button`.

A more workable example of what I imagine you are ultimately attempting to accomplish may resemble something like the following:

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import choice

root = tk.Tk()

bits = 8
rows = 8

numbers = [0, 1]

matrix_locations = [(x, y + 1) for x in range(bits) for y in range(rows)]
matrix_texts     = []
matrix_labels    = []

result_locations = [(x, y + 1) for x in range(bits, bits + 1) for y in range(rows)]
result_texts     = []
result_labels    = []

def generate_labels():

    for index, location in enumerate(matrix_locations):

        matrix_texts.append(tk.StringVar())
        matrix_texts[index].set(choice(numbers))

        matrix_labels.append(tk.Label(root, textvariable = matrix_texts[index]))
        matrix_labels[index].grid(row = location[1], column = location[0], padx = 2, pady = 2)

    for index, location in enumerate(result_locations):

        result_texts.append(tk.StringVar())
        result_texts[index].set("")

        result_labels.append(tk.Label(root, textvariable = result_texts[index]))
        result_labels[index].grid(row = location[1], column = location[0], padx = 2, pady = 2, sticky = "W")

    read_matrix()

def update_matrix():

    for text in matrix_texts:

        text.set(choice(numbers))

    read_matrix()

def read_matrix():

    string_binaries = ["" for row in range(rows)]

    for index, location in enumerate(matrix_locations):

        string_binaries[location[1] - 1] += str(matrix_texts[index].get())

    denaries = [int(string, base = 2) for string in string_binaries]

    for row in range(rows):

        result_texts[row].set(" = {}".format(denaries[row]))

binary_label = tk.Label(root, text = "Binaries")
binary_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = bits)

denary_label = tk.Label(root, text = "Denaries")
denary_label.grid(row = 0, column = bits)

generate_labels()

update_matrix_button = tk.Button(root, text = "Update matrix", command = update_matrix)
update_matrix_button.grid(row = rows + 1, column = 0, columnspan = bits + 1, sticky = "EW")

root.mainloop()
```

---

**Sample output:**

After execution:

[image: after execution]

After hitting the "Update matrix" button:

[image: after hitting the update matrix button]